# how to show the time correctly in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

I have a function in ruby on rails project.
it can create a certain task with task name and due date. after created it  will show the due date of a task.

When I create a task the task name and due date are stored in the database like:

task_name: working ,   due_date: 2013-05-15 11:06:00

They are stored correctly in the database .
but when you show the task information the due time is always two hour late.

it shows 2013-05-15 13:06:00 instead of 2013-05-15 11:06:00
and the show related code like below

```
l(assigned.due_at.localtime, :format => :mmddhhss)
```

I don't know what is the

```
 l()
```

function is used for.
how to set the time correctly.

Comment: try `l assigned.due_at.localtime, :format => :mmddhhss , :locale => 'id'` i'm using locale `id`

Answer (score 2):

The l() method is localizing the time for your specific timezone.

I am at Spain so:

```
l(Time.now) # I18n.l(Time.now) if you are testing trough the console
```

should output:

```
"martes, 07 de mayo de 2013 12:16:38 +0200"
```

Look at the +0200 at the end of the string, it means "plus two hours from UTC time". UTC time is the Universal Time, formerly known as Greenwich Time.

So it seems that you are storing your data using UTC time, and then showing a Timezone time with +2 hours from UTC. What timezone have you defined for your application?

Answer (score 0):

you can user `strftime()` so that you can format the Date/time whatever you want.
You can use this as reference [strftime()](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)